# Are there any good concurrency/parallelism books out there that are NOT focused on Java?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, parallel-processing

I want a more C++/Linux oriented book. I do have some basics of multithreading/parallel programming under my belt, but I want to both brush my skills and improve them further.

Comment: There is C++ Concurrency in Action [early access](http://www.manning.com/williams/), [preoder](http://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770), but it's C++ oriented, not pthreads-oriented.

Comment: I like Bill Lewis and Daniel Berg "Pthreads Primer"

Comment: Why are you guys so shy posting these as answers? They're proper answers!

Comment: For whatever it's worth, the one book I'd recommend for *serious* study would be: http://www.amazon.com/Art-Multiprocessor-Programming-Maurice-Herlihy/dp/0123705916/.  Yes, the examples are in Java - but the material applies to *any* language, not just Java.  IMHO...

Comment: @wilhelmtell Mine is a comment because I don't think it answers the question (OP expects pthreads programming, which is quite different from C++11 threads/atomics programming).

Comment: I will take that pthreads out of my question them. :) I'm more interested in concurrency in a C/C++ environment than in any single library.

Comment: the ART OF MULTIPROCESSOR PROGRAMMING and C++ CONCURRENCY IN ACTION seems like exactly what I'm looking for. The former is, I think, more tuned to my actual knowledge level while the later sounds more "advanced", at least for what I could grasp from the table of contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference for pthreads is *Programming with POSIX Threads*, by David Butenhof; in addition to the specifics of pthreads, it presents a lot of very good information about concurrency in general.  It is, however, strictly C, and it doesn't really say much about parallel programming.  Still, I'd definitely recommend it.

There's also *C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading*, by Anthony Williams.  This is a very new book, and I haven't seen it yet, but the author played an important role in the standardization of threading, and I've seen articles by him, so I expect it will be very good.